# Using SqlDataRecord with DateOnly

Tags: c#, sql-server, dateonly

I've got a SQL Server user defined table with a `date` field. I represent that locally using a `DateOnly`. I represent the rows locally using `SqlDataRecord`. But it doesn't appear to support `DateOnly`. Is there a sensible way of using `SqlDataRecord` to upload `date` fields?

Comment: Yes -- by using `DateTime` (but setting the `SqlDbType` to `SqlDbType.Date`). `SqlDataRecord` predates `DateOnly` (all of ADO.NET does, for that matter).

Comment: "Doesn't appear to support" is another way of saying "I can't find an API"